# How to injecting user-defined fields in Debian binary package control files

Tags: debian, package-management, dpkg, deb

It's possible to add user-defined fields in the debian/control file using the `XBS-` method, [as defined in the Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#user-defined-fields), and those will be injected into the binary .deb and source packages.

Something like this before calling dpkg-buildpackage will work to inject a new field into both the Source and Binary packages. But some packages don't contain debian/control as they generate it (kernel etc) so this is not always reliable.

```
sed -i "0,/^\s*$/s//XBS-Git-Branch: ${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}\n/" debian/control
dpkg-buildpackage
```

It's also possible to inject the user-defined field into the generated source package using [options passed to dpkg-source](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/dpkg-dev/dpkg-buildpackage.1.en.html) while building the package:

```
dpkg-buildpackage --source-option=-DGit-Branch=${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}
```

However, that will only inject the field into the generated source package, not the generated binary packages. Is there a method to reliably inject fields into the binary packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to modify the binary packages control files from the `--hook-buildinfo` hook that's called immediately after `debian/rules build` is called, using `dpkg-deb` to unpack/repack them.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
# deb_insert_meta.sh
#
# Inserts CI metadata into all deb files in parent directory
# Intended for use with:
# `dpkg-buildpackage --hook-buildinfo='fakeroot deb_insert_meta.sh'`
# which is the first hook after the binary deb files are generated
# but before checksums for .changes are calculated
# Should be called with 'fakeroot' so that the repacked binaries
# have their content/control ownership/permissions preserved.

pushd .. > /dev/null || exit 1

    for deb_file in *.deb; do
        [ -e "$deb_file" ] || continue

        DEB_TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)
        if [ -z "${DEB_TMPDIR}" ]; then
            echo "Failed to create a temporary work directory"
            exit 1
        fi

        dpkg-deb -R "${deb_file}" "${DEB_TMPDIR}"

        if [ -e "${DEB_TMPDIR}/DEBIAN/control" ]; then
            if [ -n "${CI_PROJECT_PATH}" ]; then
                echo "Git-Repo: ${CI_PROJECT_PATH}" >> "${DEB_TMPDIR}/DEBIAN/control"
            fi
            if [ -n "${CI_COMMIT_SHA}" ]; then
                echo "Git-Hash: ${CI_COMMIT_SHA}" >> "${DEB_TMPDIR}/DEBIAN/control"
            fi
            if [ -n "${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}" ]; then
                echo "Git-Branch: ${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}" >> "${DEB_TMPDIR}/DEBIAN/control"
            fi

            dpkg-deb -b "${DEB_TMPDIR}" "${deb_file}"

        fi

        rm -rf "${DEB_TMPDIR}"

    done

popd > /dev/null || exit 1

exit 0
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems your underlying problem is not having `debian/control` in all cases. The fix for that is always to start from source packages, since they have to provide a `debian/control` file. Any other approach is going to involve running part of the build directly, since `dpkg-buildpackage` requires `debian/control`; for example, you could run `debian/rules build`, and then patch `debian/control` (which must exist at this point) before running `debian/rules binary` (which produces the binary packages).

To control what goes into the binary packages’ `control` file, you can also add options for `dpkg-gencontrol`, *e.g.* using `dh_gencontrol`:

```make
override_dh_gencontrol:
        dh_gencontrol -- -Dfoo=bar
```

will add a `Foo: bar` entry to your binary packages’ `control` files. This is probably more useful in your scenario.

You’ll need to change `debian/rules` to do this; you can use `dh_gencontrol` as above, or `dpkg-gencontrol` directly if the package doesn’t use `dh`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful bit of information.
I'm not sure it helps me, as making that change to debian/rules using sed, for an arbitrary package, is even less reliable than my original sed modification of debian/control.
I'm looking for method to inject fields into both the generated source/binary packages when building an arbitrary package with dpkg-buildpackage (or gbp).

Comment: Ah right, I hadn’t understood that this is for arbitrary packages that you don’t necessarily want to modify.

Comment: See the updated answer.